# SetFTP access to 2nd nic

Tags: domain, ftp, workgroup, nic

I have a situation where we have our main LAN/Domain that all users connect to and provides access to the WEB. We have a couple of individuals who on occasion will begin an extended FTP download, sometimes taking an hour or more to download. We are not a big company and have just upgraded from DSL to T1 lines. But we still get complaints when the FTP downloads start.

Our DSL modem is still active and I would like to get the users to use it for FTP downloads (only). My current solution has the user physically switching cables from one network to the other and logging in to the local domain for FTP access, and then switch back in order to move the files to a folder he can access from his 'domain-connected' PC. I have 2 nics in the machine, but I cannot seem to get them to both work concurrently. The users avoid using it, saying it's too much trouble.

SoI'd like to set up something on the user's PC, instead of using a dedicated PC. How can I set up a users PC so that he can use the resources of our domain, except when he downloads files with an FTP client or using HTTP file download protocols, when I want the user to use the DSL connection.

(Note: For now my concern is for a single user, though a genral solution that would work for the 2 or 3 users that need it would be useful)

I am a humble programmer with almost 30 years on a keyboard. I am not a network admin, though I have fiddled with it plenty of times, but just basic stuff.

I mention this as I saw lots of answered questions concerning my general topic, but found nothing specific enough that I felt I could apply them to my situation. So the ansers may be herre, but I may just not understand the relationships. I may need some help with the more complex issues.

Thanks.

Marshall

I think this is the right place, but regardless, I know this question will get routed properly if it isn't. I love this site.

Answer (score 1):

Setup the second NIC with a static IP and no gateway or DNS. Use a [static route](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_pro_addstaticroute.mspx?mfr=true) for the IP of the ftp site to use the second NIC.

*route add destination mask subnetmask gateway metric costmetric if interface*

**EXAMPLE**

**NIC1 (T1)**
IP: 10.10.1.100
SUBNETMASK: 255.255.255.0
GATEWAY: 10.10.1.1
DNS: 10.10.1.1

**NIC2 (DSL)**
IP: 192.168.1.200
SUBNETMASK: 255.255.255.0
GATEWAY: [blank]
DNS: [blank]

IP of you DSL router: 192.168.1.2
FTP SITE: 149.20.4.71

route -p add 149.20.4.71 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.2

Comment: This works for remote FTP Sites, I take it? There are a number of FTP Sites we need to access. I'm using FTPzilla for a client. 
>>Setup the second nic with a static IP -- Meaning something from within my domain's range of IP addresses (i.e. 192.168.n.0-256). And I am assuming you are refering to the actual FTP address (IP address) when you say 'static route'? I'm not sure how to tell it to use the second nic. Do I include it's mac address in the FTP address?

Comment: Yes it works for remote sites. I have edited to include an example. You can also use the interface. You get the interface identifier from the "route print" command. Under interfaces it is the number on the left of each interface. "12...00 11 22 33 44 55  ..." would use "if 12". Is that a little more clear?